# DateTime.Parse(string)' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException' System.DateTime {System.FormatException}

Tags: datetime

`DateTime.Parse(string)` threw an exception of type `System.FormatException` `System.DateTime {System.FormatException}` for different cultures.

Is there a way to convert date stored in string from any culture into datetime format?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo =  new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("13/12/2009", cultureinfo);
```

Comment: i need a generic solution as site is used all over the globe and take culture from user profile.

Comment: there is nothing like that, you cant generalize it, what can you do to force culture, and make everybody use it